# Data-conditions in PHP array AND instead of OR

Tags: php, arrays

The code below outputs date-conditions like this:

```
data-conditions="[[{"field":"field_5ed4181bd63dc","operator":"==","value":"1"},{"field":"field_5ed4178dd63d7","operator":"!=","value":"20200701"}],[{"field":"field_5ed4181bd63dc","operator":"==","value":"1"},{"field":"field_5ed4178dd63d7","operator":"!=","value":"20200702"}]]"
```

In simple terms it outputs the data-conditions like this:

```
if field_5ed4181bd63dc == 1 AND DATE != 20200701 OR if field_5ed4181bd63dc == 1 AND DATE != 20200701 OR ...
```

and so on.

So what it should do is check BLACKOUT dates when field_5ed4181bd63dc == 1

But in this case the BLACKOUT dates won't have any effect regardless if you choose 20200701 or 20200702, because it always fulfill one of the condition, due to the OR operator.

I guess the code needs to be rewritten a little so it will output the data-conditions like this:

```
if field_5ed4181bd63dc == 1 AND DATE != 20200701 AND DATE != 20200702 AND DATE != ...
```

and so on.

Can someone help me with this?

```
// Apply conditions to fields
add_filter('acf/prepare_field/name=booking_time_session_1', 'yl_check_booking_setting_exceptions_session_1');
function yl_check_booking_setting_exceptions_session_1($field){
  $conditions = array();
  if (have_rows('booking_setting_exceptions', 'booking_settings')) {
    while (have_rows('booking_setting_exceptions', 'booking_settings')) {
      the_row();
        if (get_sub_field('booking_setting_exceptions_session') == '1') {
        $date = date_i18n('Ymd', strtotime(get_sub_field('booking_setting_exceptions_date', 'booking_settings')));
        if (empty($date)) {
          // no date, skip this row
          continue;
        }
        // Add the condition to the field
        $conditions[] =
          array(
               array(
                'field'   => 'field_5ed4181bd63dc', // Time field session 1 in the form
                'operator'  => '==', // If Value is same, then show the field
                'value'   => '1', // Compare against session option page value
              ),
              array(
                'field'   => 'field_5ed4178dd63d7', // Date field in the form
                'operator'  => '!=', // If Value is different, then show the field
                'value'   => $date, // Compare against date option page value
              ),
            );
        }
    } // end while have_rows
  } // end if have_rows
  $field['conditional_logic'] = $conditions;
  // Return
  return $field;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you study a tutorial on boolean operations and order of operations

Comment: Also i might add why reinvent trying to write your own expression parser? Wouldn't it be easier to sanitize the vars and use `eval()`? Emphasis on the "sanitize" part for the nay-sayers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. Have fun with it.... I will for sure :)

```
add_filter('acf/prepare_field/name=booking_time_session_1', 'yl_check_booking_setting_exceptions_session_1');
function yl_check_booking_setting_exceptions_session_1($field){
    
    // Reset conditions
    // Warning: Conditions set in the UI won't be compatible!
    $conditions = array();

    // Creating Base Condition
    $conditions[] = array(
        array(
            'field'     => 'field_5ed4181bd63dc',
            'operator'  => '==',
            'value'     => '1',
        )
    );

    if(have_rows('booking_setting_exceptions', 'booking_settings')):
        while(have_rows('booking_setting_exceptions', 'booking_settings')): the_row();
        
            // Check: Booking Settings Exceptions Session
            if(get_sub_field('booking_setting_exceptions_session') != '1')
                continue;
            
            $date = date_i18n('Ymd', strtotime(get_sub_field('booking_setting_exceptions_date', 'booking_settings')));
            
            // Check: Booking Settings Exceptions Date
            if(empty($date))
                continue;
            
            // Adding a new AND condition inside Base condition, at the index = 0
            $conditions[0][] = array(
                'field'     => 'field_5ed4178dd63d7',
                'operator'  => '!=',
                'value'     => $date,
            );
        
        endwhile;
    endif;

    // Setting the full condition
    $field['conditional_logic'] = $conditions;
     
     return $field;
    
}
```